# How to make AutoIt script identify browse window when run in remote machine with Selenium grid?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, grid, autoit

In a remote machine where Selenium Grid is configured - I integrated an AutoIT script with Selenium script to upload a file, but the browser window is not being identified by AutoIT. However, the same AutoIT script is identifying the browser window in my local machine when the selenium script is run from my local machine (without grid).

Any workarounds or suggestions to make it work on a remote machine with Selenium Grid, please?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the remote machine is locked, and thus AutoIT can not work. It works on your desktop because it is not locked.

Solution: Keep the desktop unlocked (no screensaver etc). Of course, this reduces the security as well.

Possible other solution: Instead of AutoIT, use Kantu for the [file uploads](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs#fileupload). Kantu works inside Chromium, and runs fine on locked system and/or [headless](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs#headless).

Comment: Thanks Steven for the reply, I will try Kantu. And the remote machine is not locked, I could see the execution till the Browse window (Windows OS) opens but AutoIt script not identifying that window - I think its due to Selenium Grid setup in remote machine?